# CSS not displying as expected

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have been building a website, and everything has worked as expected until I suddenly could not get anything to display on the same line even though similar code has worked before on this website. The site is also displaying images differently even though it's the same image and div CSS. I am building out on Drupal with HTML and CSS. My HTML code is

```
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/spicy-avocado-lime"><div class="spicy-avocado-lime">SPICY AVOCADO & LIME</div></a>
<div class="textblock"></div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/toasted-almond-ginger"><div class ="toasted-almond-ginger">TOASTED ALMOND & GINGER</div></a>
<div class="textblock"></div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/local-apple-bacon"><div class="local-apple-bacon-bowl">LOCAL APPLE & BACON BOWL</div></a>
<div class="textblock"></div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="kale-grain-bowls/power-bowl"><div class="power-bowl">POWER BOWL</div></a><div class="textblock"></div></div>
```

My css is:

```
.foodblock{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 15px;
    height: 300px;
}
.textblock{
    float: left;
}
.spicy-avocado-lime{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
}
.toasted-almond-ginger{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
}
.local-apple-bacon-bowl{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
}
.power-bowl{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
}/*for mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"]{
        width:100%;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16%;}
    .col-m-2-5 {width: 21.55%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 24%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 32.5%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 40%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 48%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 56%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 65.7%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 72%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 80%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 88%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 96%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    /*for mobile desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8%;}
    .col-2-5 {width: 21.55%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16%;}
    .col-3 {width: 24%;}
    .col-4 {width: 32.5%;}
    .col-5 {width: 40%;}
    .col-6 {width: 48%;}
    .col-7 {width: 56%;}
    .col-8 {width: 65.7%;}
    .col-9 {width: 72%;}
    .col-10 {width: 80%;}
    .col-11 {width: 88%;}
    .col-12 {width: 96%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove clear:both; property from the .foodblock selector in your css. That will display your cols inline.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had already tried removing it but apparently not. This fixed the issue if it not displaying inline. The issue of the power-bowl div image displaying smaller than all the other images though still exists.

Comment: All your code looks valid and all the divs including power-bowl are the same. I think you already know this, if you set smaller width like 20% of your col divs they will be inline. Now, I don't have the full link to your images so I can't see if maybe you need to save the images the same size. The power-bowl div just appears smaller, because there are two words in it and the other divs have more. Power-bowl div, local-bacon-apple etc. divs will fill inherit the size from col divs.

Comment: My images are inline thanks to your fix of removing clear. The div is most definitely smaller. All of the images are the same so they should be the same size. I am including a link to an image of my site. http://imgur.com/KSlPTEF. The word count shouldn't affect this though because of the col div's setting the width no?

Comment: Ahhh, right. Set the width of the power-bowl, local-bacon and the other two divs to 100%. That will do it.

Comment: Thanks, I was just able to test this out today and it appears to have worked thank you.

Comment: I now can not move the div's up the page to be inline with the object above them. I have tried adding a bottom tag the CSS of the divs. I also tried adding another div around these divs and applying the bottom tag to that but I have so far had no success.

Comment: Can you provide the link? I can help you troubleshoot if I have the link. Or, can you post the whole code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response yesterday. I can't post a link cause it is currently on an internal dev server. I am going to post the code here. the HTML is at http://pastebin.com/raw/FPsf18KU and the CSS is at http://pastebin.com/raw/PEJRaUqS

Comment: I forgot to include these lines into the css .foodblock{
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 height: 400px;
 bottom: 50px;
}
.textblock{
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}